# Change Upload control Types of file

Tags: asp.net, upload, controls

I have added validation to validate if the user has chosen .doc file or not. But I want to show only .doc files by changing the "files of type to .doc" in file upload window. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot limit the types the file upload dialog that is generated by the browser in most cases, but there are some ways to work around this by using a flash file upload component like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) .

I think some latest versions of some browsers may have an attribute to control this, but it is specific to those browsers and not ready to be relied on, but maybe in the future this will be an option.